# Use variable inside constant in angularjs and pass it to another controller

Tags: angularjs

I want to generate dynamic url in angularjs where I will get parameters from input fields and save the values in {{origin.name}} and {{destination.name}}

My question is i want to use this variable value in url

http://something.com/app_bus_available.php?origin={{origin.name}}&destination={{destination.name}}

And also pass this url to another controller

How to make this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the route params from the current url with [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams), which will let you put them into your current controller.  Other ways of accessing the current url include [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location), which can access the raw url and $route, which allows easy swapping of route params.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a service where you can store the current url with the current parameters for origin and destination. And then inject this service in the other controller and get it from there.

Another option is to broadcast an event which the other controller listens to.

You got one other suggestion already.

Get back if you need more information how to do it.